# pandas: difference between two series return None

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Hi I'm trying to find the difference between two series but it return an empty list.

```
new_main_file = pd.read_excel('result_concat.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
new_main_file.Title.count()#=> 11 620
len(new_main_file.Title.unique())#=> 10 436

#Difference
pd.Series(list(set(new_main_file.Title) - set(new_main_file.Title.unique())))
#Series([], dtype: float64)
```

I am trying to find which title are in duplicate

Comment: there is no duplicates in `set`, so `set(new_main_file.Title)` and `set(new_main_file.Title.unique())` contain exactly the same elements. Taking difference leads to empty set, and that's why you see `None` is returned.

Comment: Thks @JianxunLi ! But why does the length is different. 11 620 vs 10 436

Comment: `count` returns the number of `non-NaN` values in your `Title` columns, and it contains duplicated values. `unique` of course doesn't contain duplicated values, and that's why its `len` is less than `count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set()` and `.unique()` do the same thing so `set(df.col) = set(df.col.unique())`, and that's why `None` is returned.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
# ========================================================
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('abcdefghigk'), size=20), columns=['col'])
df

   col
0    f
1    a
2    d
3    d
4    h
5    g
6    d
7    f
8    c
9    e
10   h
11   g
12   i
13   i
14   k
15   b
16   g
17   h
18   h
19   i


df['col'].count()  # output 20
len(df['col'].unique())  # output 10
set(df.col)
# output {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'}
set(df.col.unique())
# output {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'}
set(df.col) - set(df.col.unique())
# output set()


# processing
# ======================================================
res = df['col'].value_counts()

h    4
i    3
d    3
g    3
f    2
b    1
k    1
c    1
e    1
a    1
dtype: int64

# duplicated titles
res.index[res>1].tolist()

['h', 'i', 'd', 'g', 'f']
```